# BigQuery: Cost for Tabledata: list with "startIndex" and "maxResults"

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to get records from about 10 billion records separately. Although I had tried "select...limit x offset y", it is too expensive. I got a surprising bill and shocked.

Now I am considering using "Tabledata: list" with "startIndex" and "maxResults". But I am not sure if the cost is much cheaper than "select...limit x offset y" or not. Does "maxResults" affect the cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bigquery.tabledata.list()` is a free operation, but extracting 10 billion records will be too slow.

Instead, export to GCS with an `extract job` (which is also a free operation in BigQuery):

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will try it!